# Unable to Parse Kafka server logs format into RSYS

Tags: json, apache-kafka, fluentd, rsyslog

Trying to send Kafka server logs from Rsys to FLuentd.
First converted the Kafka server log into Json, and then sending the Json logs from rsys.

VM1: Kafka,Rsyslog installed
VM2: FuentD

Example of Kafka server logs.

```
{"timestamp":"2022-07-29 07:12:18","level":"ERROR","logger":"io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka","thread":"main","message":"Fatal error during SupportedServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown","stacktrace":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: advertised.listeners cannot use the nonroutable meta-address 0.0.0.0. Use a routable IP address.\n\tat scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)\n\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1492)\n\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1460)\n\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1114)\n\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1094)\n\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1091)\n\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala)\n\tat io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.<init>(SupportedServerStartable.java:52)\n\tat io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:45)"}
```

I've tried the below configuration but it's not giving the right output.
rsyslog.conf

```
$ModLoad imfile
$ModLoad immark
$ModLoad imtcp
$ModLoad imudp
$ModLoad imuxsock

#Template for  logs
template(name="elastic"
  type="list") {
      property(name="hostname")
      constant(value=" ") property(name="syslogtag")
      property(name="msg")
      constant(value="\n")
}


#Provides UDP syslog reception
$UDPServerRun 514

$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputFileName /var/log/kafka/server.log
$InputFileTag kafkalogs:
$InputFileStateFile kafkalogs
$InputFileFacility local0
$InputRunFileMonitor

:syslogtag, isequal, "kafkalogs:" {
  :msg, contains, "ERROR" {
    local0.* /var/log/kafkalog_error.log
    local0.* @fluentdvmip:5144
  }
  stop
}
```

td-agent.conf

```
    <system>
  worker 2
</system>

<source>
  @type syslog
  port 5142
  tag system
</source>

<match system.**>
  @type stdout
</match>

<source>
  @type udp
  port 5144
  tag kafkalogs
  <parse>
  @type json
   time_type string
   time_format %yyyy-%MM-%dd %HH:%mm:%ss
  </parse>
</source>


<match kafka.**>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

cat /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log

```
2022-07-29 07:56:24 +0000 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched data="<133>Jul 29 07:56:24 techsrv01 kafkalogs: {\"timestamp\":\"2022-07-29 07:56:23\",\"level\":\"ERROR\",\"logger\":\"io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka\",\"thread\":\"main\",\"message\":\"Fatal error during SupportedServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown\",\"stacktrace\":\"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: advertised.listeners cannot use the nonroutable meta-address 0.0.0.0. Use a routable IP address.\\n\\tat scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)\\n\\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1492)\\n\\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1460)\\n\\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1114)\\n\\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1094)\\n\\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1091)\\n\\tat kafka.server.KafkaConfig.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala)\\n\\tat io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.<init>(SupportedServerStartable.java:52)\\n\\tat io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:45)\"}"
```

As, we can see the td-agent logs is not correct format as compared to kafka logs.
How the rsyslog can be made equivalent to actual kafka logs. With every word there is \ added.

Comment: SO is **not** a forum. Please read [How to I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as *some* of your recent asked questions are following the same pattern: "How do i fix this?" - without providing any information on what you've tried to solve the problem or even a detailed explanation of what you're trying to achieve and what exactly is *going wrong*. Instead you're only posting the needed files to solve the problem (which by itself is good), but then just saying *"Please fix this for me"*.

Comment: Given that your logs appear to be in JSON format, `contains, "ERROR"` probably isn't what you want. You should be able to actually parse the JSON to check `level == "ERROR"`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work using the below configurations:

RSYSLOG.conf

```
$ModLoad imfile
$ModLoad immark
$ModLoad imtcp
$ModLoad imudp
$ModLoad imuxsock

#Template for  logs
template(name="elastic"
  type="list") {
      property(name="hostname")
      constant(value=" ") property(name="syslogtag")
      property(name="msg")
      constant(value="\n")
}
#Provides UDP syslog reception
$UDPServerRun 514

$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputFileName /var/log/kafka/server.log
$InputFileTag kafkalogs:
$InputFileStateFile kafkalogs
$InputFileFacility local0
$InputRunFileMonitor

:syslogtag, isequal, "kafkalogs:" {
  :msg, contains, "ERROR" {
    local0.* /var/log/kafkalog_error.log
    local0.* @fluentdvmip:5144
  }
  stop
}
```

td-agent.conf

```
<system>
  worker 2
</system>

<source>
  @type syslog
  port 5142
  tag system
</source>

<match system.**>
  @type stdout
</match>

<match kafka.**>
  @type stdout
</match>

<source>
  @type syslog
  port 5144
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag kafka_error
</source>

<match kafka_error**>
  @type elasticsearch
  host ElasticVMIP or HOSTNAME
  port 9200
  index_name kafka_error_write
  include_timestamp true


  # connection configs
    reconnect_on_error true
    reload_on_failure true
    slow_flush_log_threshold 90

  # buffer configs
  <buffer>
    @type file
    path /data/opt/fluentd/buffer/kafka_error_write
    chunk_limit_size 32MB
    total_limit_size 20GB
    flush_thread_count 8
    flush_mode interval
    retry_type exponential_backoff
    retry_timeout 10s
    retry_max_interval 30
    overflow_action drop_oldest_chunk
    flush_interval 5s
  </buffer>
</match>
```

Result was complete output in Elastic

[image]